# Cannot overwrite existing picture in Windows 10 Photos app

Tags: windows-10, photos

When editing a picture in the Windows 10 Photos app, I cannot save over the existing file. The only button available is "Save a copy". I'm sure the app used to have a regular Save button as well, though. Any ideas where it might have gone?

I'm running Windows 10 version 1511 (build 10586.36), Photos app version is 15.1208.10480.0.

Comment: Is the photo is a special folder where you have no write access? Many programs are not able to bring up the Admin-Confirm-you-Authorize-this box and instead just don't save there.

Comment: No, the problem occurs with folders in my OneDrive (camera roll as well as self-created album folders). Nothing special about them.

Comment: I don't use OneDrive but that is probably anything but a normal folder. I recommend you verify the behavior with a definitive standard folder like `C:\Temp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem only occurs with pictures taken by my Lumia 950, specifically those that use Rich Capture. Photos taken in manual mode, or with my older Lumia 920 which doesn't support Rich Capture, do not have this problem and can be overwritten just fine. I only switched phones recently, which is why I hadn't noticed the problem before.

So basically the Windows 10 Photos app does not allow saving over images taken with a Lumia phone in Rich Capture mode:

[image]

The solution is very simple - rename the file to remove the "Rich" part from the filename. This causes the Save button to reappear:

[image]

The following PowerShell snippet can quickly rename all files in a folder:

```
gci | ren -newname { $_.name -replace "_Rich", "" }
```